# How to forward fill a column subset with method chaining?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, method-chaining

I have a dataframe that contains information about days. Each day has two phases.

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(dict(
    day=[0, 1, 2],
    phase1=[1, 0, 2],
    phase2=[5, 0, 7],
))
```

The goal is to forward fill days on which both phases are 0. The expected output looks like this

```
out_wanted = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    day=[0, 1, 2],
    phase1=[1, 1, 2],
    phase2=[5, 5, 7],
))
```

I am searching for a solution to this problem **that works with method chaining**. The syntax should somewhat look like this:

```
out_wanted = (
    df
    .methodA(...)
    .methodB(...)
    .forward_fill_magic()
    .methodC(...)
    .methodD(...)
)
```

How can I do that?

---

**Update:**

Let's imagine `df` has two columns named `day` and `x` that can contain zeros and I want to avoid replacing any values in them with nan. How would I do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    day=[0, 1, 2],
    phase1=[1, 0, 2],
    phase2=[5, 0, 7],
    x=[1, 2, 3]
))
```

The current proposed solution gives me an ValueError

```
df = (
    df.set_index(["day", "x"])
    .mask(df.eq(0))
    .ffill(downcast= 'infer')
)
```

-> `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without setting (and later resetting) an index and with an explicit selection of columns to be filled. It also fills only if both columns are equal to 0 (which I think was part of the requirements).

```py
def forward_fillmagic(df, colnames):
    all_zero = df[colnames].eq(0).all(axis=1)
    return df.assign(**{
        colname: df[colname].mask(all_zero).ffill(downcast="infer")
        for colname in colnames
    })

df.pipe(forward_fillmagic, ["phase1", "phase2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY with `set_index` /`mask` /`ffill` :

```
df = df.set_index(["day", "x"]).mask(lambda d: d.eq(0)).ffill().reset_index()
```

ALTERNATIVE_1 :

```
df = (
    df.set_index(["day", "x"])
    .replace(0,np.nan)
    .ffill(downcast= 'infer')
)
```

ALTERNATIVE_2 :

```
df[df.filter(like = 'phase').columns] = df.filter(like= 'phase').mask(df.eq(0)).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

OUTPUT:

```
     phase1  phase2
day                
0         1       5
1         1       5
2         2       7
```

Comment: Let's imagine `df` has two columns named `day` and `x` that can contain zeros and I want to avoid replacing any values in them with `nan`. How would I do that? `df.set_index(["day", "x"]).mask(df.eq(0)).mask(df.eq(0)).ffill()` gives me this error `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names`

Comment: Can you add the dataframe to the question? @zwithouta

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Added 2 alternatives @zwithouta

Comment: Thanks. Alternative 1 is working also with setting/resetting multiple columns as index. Alternative 2 is not working with method chaining is it?

Comment: First proposed solution can be fixed like this to work also with setting/resetting multiple columns as index. `df.set_index(["day", "x"]).mask(lambda d: d.eq(0)).ffill().reset_index()`. Could you update your answer accordingly? :)

Comment: Updated @zwithouta